# not getting response from virtualhosts apache2 ubuntu14

Tags: 14.04, apache2

Hi I have a file geometrixxig.com.conf under my sites-enabled folder. After enabling that file i reloaded the apache service. I used the commands :

```
 sudo a2ensite geometrixxig.com
```

Below is my conf file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
   ServerName geometrixxig.com
   ServerAlias www.geometrixxig.com
   DocumentRoot "/opt/communique/dispatcher/cache/content/geometrixx"
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^/$ /content/geometrixx/en.html [PT,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/apps
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/etc
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/libs
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tmp
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/var
   RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /content/geometrixx/en/$1 [PT]
    <Directory "/opt/communique/dispatcher/cache/content/geometrixx">
     <IfModule disp_apache2.c>
           SetHandler dispatcher-handler
           ModMimeUsePathInfo On
         </IfModule>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride all
         Order Allow,Deny
         Allow from all
 </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

When i hit http://geometrixxig.com/ I am getting an error : `You don't have permission to access /content/geometrixx/en.html on this server.`

I have checked permission all are 777, but not getting why its not working.

If i hit http://localhost/content/geometrixx/en.html i get the page

Thanks

Comment: OK Require all granted, fixed my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing ownership recursively?

> chown -R www-data:www-data
>   /opt/communique/dispatcher/cache/content/geometrixx

Comment: Hi, I replaced Order Allow,Deny Allow from all with   Require all granted fixed my issue

Comment: @VDhim: You might want to put that in as an answer and accept that as the solution